# Show specific category in database

Tags: sql

I have two tables in my database. One named `jokes` and the other named `category`.

This is the PHP which displays each joke with a category name.

```
SELECT  jokes.*, 
        category.name 
FROM jokes jokes 
LEFT JOIN category category ON category.category_id = jokes.category_id 
ORDER BY joke_id DESC';
```

How would i change the query of the `$sql` variable to just show a specific category from the table? For example, a short jokes page which only shows the short jokes.

Comment: If you only ask for a SQL query, then why have you added all that PHP code? You should also explain your schema and add sample data with its expected output

Comment: Sorry, i have edited it now.

Comment: It is also not neccessary to use `jokes jokes` the second instance of joke could be used as a shorthand, eg: `FROM jokes AS j`

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that your question has nothing to do with PHP, it's just a sql question.

Anyway, the bottom line of all queries that are bound to a single category is to add the WHERE keyword after you've listed the table name, following by the column name you wish to search by and it's search-value.

Example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM joke j WHERE j.category  = :cat";
```

Assuming that you'll be clever enough to use prepared statements. Then you could execute an array of variables, having `short` or it's actual id as the variable, indicating what category to search for.

It's, in general, a bad practise to `SELECT *` from a table since it's a performance issue, do you really need all the data? Do you wish to make the query more clear by telling what columns are desired from the table?

For your case:

```
$sql = 'SELECT jokes.*, category.name 
FROM jokes jokes 
LEFT JOIN category category 
ON category.category_id = jokes.category_id 
WHERE jokes.category_id = :cat 
ORDER BY joke_id DESC';
```

Comment: hi @jonast92, i would just be wanting to select just one category from the table, which in this example would be `short` jokes category. Would this be the query to retrieve this data?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT jokes.*, category.name FROM jokes jokes 
LEFT JOIN category category ON category.category_id = jokes.category_id 
WHERE category.category_id = x
ORDER BY joke_id DESC
```

Also, why on earth are you giving your tables an alias with the same name
?

`SELECT * FROM jokes j`
is the typical way.